# Windows phone 8 image uploading to windows azure

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload Image from my windows phone 8 application to azure , I have searched a

lot  and found various solutions in windows phone 7 all are using

> "Phone.Storage"

, but when I try to install it for my windows phone 8 app , it throw error.
I have also tried  vaious packages using nuget package manager but every one installation faild at

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.7.0.3'. Install
>   failed. Rolling back...

Please help me resolve this issue, and if there exist a good tutorial , please share .

Zauk

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, the reason was that the NuGet version that ships with VS2012 RTM doesn't support WP8. Can you try to  update your NuGet package manager to the latest version.

Go to

```
Menu Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery -> NuGet
```

update restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error when trying to install the Azure Storage library from Nuget. "Could not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager'" . That is because the package you are trying to install does not include the Windows Phone 8 library.
As a fix: Use this command from the package manager console: 
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage-Preview -Pre

Here is some documentation on how to implement it, after you are done installing the Azure Storage SDK
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/